# How to add Scrollview that include Constraintlayout to a layout "scrollable constraintlayout"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a complicated `Layout` that  created with `constraintlayout` and i need to scroll Vertically some part of it with `scroll view` and of Course this `scroll view` must include `constraintlayout` too,
Is any Body can help ?

I bring My code maybe it could help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02676399" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98053527" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.019151846" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLineH20to25Percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20519836" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minWidth="75dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e1e1e1"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/get_location_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="btn_clicked"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_city"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edit_city"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_city"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edit_city" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather_condition_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edit_city"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edit_city"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_city" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather_temp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/current_weather_condition_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/current_weather_condition_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_weather_condition_view" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todayNameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideLineH20to25Percent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todayView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Today"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/todayNameView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/todayNameView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todayMinTemperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/todayMaxTemperature"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineRight"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/todayMaxTemperature" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todayMaxTemperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineRight"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideLineH20to25Percent" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/todayNameView" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideLineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guidelineMiddleH"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view1" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon1"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineMiddleH"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineMiddleH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgIcon1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgIcon1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgIcon1" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon3"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgIcon2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgIcon2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgIcon2" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon4"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgIcon3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgIcon3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgIcon3" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon5"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgIcon4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgIcon4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgIcon4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thirdDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourthDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fivthDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon5"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxTemp1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxTemp2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxTemp3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxTemp4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxTemp5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgIcon5" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minTemp1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maxTemp1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minTemp2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maxTemp2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minTemp3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maxTemp3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minTemp4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maxTemp4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minTemp5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maxTemp5" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgIcon5" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wind_name_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Wind"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentSpeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wind_name_view" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pressure_name_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="PRESSURE"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineMiddleH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/currentFeelTemperature" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentPressure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pressure_name_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pressure_name_view" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feelLike_name_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="FEELS LIKE"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineMiddleH"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentFeelTemperature"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/feelLike_name_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feelLike_name_view" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/humidity_name_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="HUMIDITY"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/currentSpeed" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentHumidity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/humidity_name_view" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the ScrollView.

**Don't forget that If you constraint some view's bottom to constraint layout's bottom.Scrollview could not scroll.**

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf=“parent”
```

*It seems that it is working, I don't know what dependency you were working with but in this one*

**implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'**

Is working, this is what I did

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="377dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="176dp"
                    android:layout_height="268dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView17"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Account #"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <!--            <TextView-->
                    <!--                android:id="@+id/textView9"-->
                    <!--                android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"-->
                    <!--                android:text="Company Name "-->
                    <!--                android:textColor="#000000"-->
                    <!--                android:textSize="18sp" />-->

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Phone"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Serial number"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Product name "
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Brand"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Subject"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lintext"
                        android:text="Problem Details "
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="187dp"
                    android:layout_height="263dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/from_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ahmed hassen" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name_product"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="26 Horrya st ,helioplis 11341" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/num_ser"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="+201111414141" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="CZ3351x4BW" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Hp SL230 Gen8 Rht half Svr" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Hp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Broken Screen" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Broken Screen and we gonna replace it " />


                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="377dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.328"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="83dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="     500"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.536"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="134dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:text="Estimated Labor"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText3"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="EGP"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.196"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.695" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/ll"
                    android:layout_width="377dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="376dp"
                    android:layout_height="93dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="A dying or cracked display doesn't mean your  laptop is a paperweight.  For most laptops, a screen replacement takes"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Problem Found "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="219dp"
                    android:layout_height="29dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                    android:text="Spare Parts Selected"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.074"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="412dp"
                    android:layout_height="49dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="  ** Kingston Kvr16N11/8 - 8Gb Ddr3 Pc3-12800 1600Mhz Non-Ecc Cl11 Desktop Memory "
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="412dp"
                    android:layout_height="49dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="  ** Kingston Kvr16N11/8 - 8Gb Ddr3 Pc3-12800 1600Mhz Non-Ecc Cl11 Desktop Memory "
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView18" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                    android:text="Estimated time"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.085"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="134dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="    6  Hours"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.224"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

                <in.shadowfax.proswipebutton.ProSwipeButton
                    android:id="@+id/awesome_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:bg_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    app:btn_text="Close Your Ticket"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_et_border"
                    android:onClick="goSignature"
                    android:text="put your signature here"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks  , it works !, But is it possible for example the first three views be fixed and didn't scroll and other views can be scroll ?

Comment: Glad that it worked with you ..
Can you explain more

Comment: Suppose we have 20 Views and i want the first three views be fixed and other (17 views below them) only can be scrolled  and all should be down only with Constraint Layout and Scroll view. when i do like you all view can be Scroll and if i put the first three views outside them other 17 Views can not be scrolled too !

Comment: I don't understand it well : ("Don't forget that If you constraint some view's bottom to constraint layout's bottom.Scrollview could not scroll ") what it mean ? of Course some views top should be under bottom of other view's bottom ) please make it clear more for me

Comment: First thing make "scroll view" at items you need , and make fixed items with only on constraintlayout , and do your constraint usaull as u do its simple need some time from you 
, and take a look here and do that example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: dear my main root layout should be ConstraintLayout